# Speakers making whistling noises

Tags: desktop-computer, speakers

When I have high CPU usage on my computer, the speaker plugged into the analog port makes whistling noises.

When I turn the sound down from the speaker, the noise goes away, but I can't hear anything else, so that's not a solution. The noises have varying pitches depending on how high the CPU usage is. The sound isn't extremely loud, nor similar to described by other people in similar situations.

There's a static noise too, but it's quiet enough that I can ignore it. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Insufficient isolation between the various circuits on your mainboard will cause this issue.

You could:

- add a ground loop to your audio path
- use better-designed speakers that most of this noise
- install a discrete audio card or device that separates and isolates the audio circuits from the mainboard circuits

Comment: Wonder where the audio stuff goes on the main board? It's all hidden by the GPU and the CPU.

Comment: It's a chip, or it's embedded in another chip on the mainboard. This is common for any onboard audio on a computer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with music2myear in that hardware changes may be required, but here's some things you could try:

- If your computer offers you a way to record the sum total of all the audio that is currently playing (sometimes labeled as a "What U Hear" recording channel), disable it: with some audio chips, it is a flawed signal path that allows noise into sound output.
- Likewise, set all recording channels that you are not actively using to zero volume and/or muted in the audio mixing settings: in particular, an unused microphone input channel with Mic Boost set to high can easily pick up interference from other components of the computer and turn it into audible noise, because of high amplification.